# Low contrast stops HoughCircles from detection(?)

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision, contrast

I am trying to build a script capable of counting how many Euros (for now just with coins) are in a picture. In order to accomplish this I am thinking of firstly locating the coins and then compare their relative size in order to know the value of each one as I've seen done in other places. My hardship lies in the first step, in the pre processing of the image.
A note is that this problem arises only when contrast between the background and certain coins is very low

I've tried various methods pre processing with different methods of detection such as connectedComponentsWithStats(), findContours() and SimpleBlobDetector, but the most successful  combination I've achieved is:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
import os

path = 'GenericImages/TP2/'
path_coins_highlighted = 'GenericImages/Highlights'
path_gaussian_blurs = 'GenericImages/Gaussian_Blurs'
dirs = os.listdir(path)
i = 0
for file in dirs:
    path2img = os.path.join(path, file)
    img = cv2.imread(path2img)

    gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

    # clahe = cv2.createCLAHE(clipLimit=40, tileGridSize=(8, 8))
    # equalized = clahe.apply(gray)

    gray_blur = cv2.GaussianBlur(gray, (15, 15), 0)
    # gray_blur = cv2.bilateralFilter(gray, 9, 65, 9)

    circles = cv2.HoughCircles(gray_blur, cv2.HOUGH_GRADIENT, 1, 15, param1=50, param2=30, minRadius=0, maxRadius=0)
    circles = np.uint16(np.around(circles))
    for x in circles[0, :]:
        cv2.circle(img, (x[0], x[1]), x[2], (0, 255, 0), 2)
        cv2.circle(img, (x[0], x[1]), 2, (0, 0, 255), 3)

    cv2.imshow('Gray', gray)
    cv2.imshow('Gaussian Blur', gray_blur)
    path_save_gaussian_blur = os.path.join(path_gaussian_blurs, str(i) + '_gaussian_blur.jpg')
    cv2.imwrite(path_save_gaussian_blur, gray_blur)
    # cv2.imshow('equalized', equalized)
    cv2.imshow('Highlights', img)
    path_save_highlights = os.path.join(path_coins_highlighted, str(i) + '_highlight.jpg')
    cv2.imwrite(path_save_highlights, img)
    i += 1
    cv2.waitKey(0)
```

The problem lies in the consistency of the detection, I believe that when it fails, it does so because there is little to no contrast between the background and the coins that HoughCircles is not detecting. The set of images below show the cases in which the algorithm fails.

SET 0:

[image: Original Image 0]
[image: Image 0 Gaussian Blur]
[image: Image 0 Highlighted]

SET1:

[image: Original Image 1]
[image: Image 1 Gaussian Blur]
[image: Image 1 Highlighted]

I've tried tweaking with equalization and a bilateral filter with different parameters in order to remove noise but keep the transition zones (contours of the coin) but I haven't found significant improvements.

I would appreciate some direction or ideas of what I should be looking for to solve this issue.

Comment: Try the sobel/canny parameters, whether the right edges are extracted.

Answer (score 4):

The lighting is non-uniform and your images are small and heavily compressed. These are the two factors that hinder a good detection. It might be difficult to control lighting but at least make sure you use lossless image formats (such as `png`) to avoid compression artifacts.

Anyway, your non-uniform lighting makes this a good case for a lighting normalization method called *Gain Division*. The idea is that you try to build a model of the background and then weight each input pixel by that model. The output gain should be relatively constant during most of the image. This is very useful because if we eliminate the non-uniform lighting we can create a foreground mask for the coins, and then we simply **approximate circles** to the coin's contours.

Let's give it a try:

```
# imports:
import cv2
import numpy as np

# image path
path = "D://opencvImages//"
fileName = "FHlbm.jpg"

# Reading an image in default mode:
inputImage = cv2.imread(path + fileName)
# Deep copy for results:
inputImageCopy = inputImage.copy()

# Get local maximum:
kernelSize = 30
maxKernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (kernelSize, kernelSize))
localMax = cv2.morphologyEx(inputImage, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, maxKernel, None, None, 1, cv2.BORDER_REFLECT101)

# Perform gain division
gainDivision = np.where(localMax == 0, 0, (inputImage / localMax))

# Clip the values to [0,255]
gainDivision = np.clip((255 * gainDivision), 0, 255)

# Convert the mat type from float to uint8:
gainDivision = gainDivision.astype("uint8")

cv2.imshow("Gain Division", gainDivision)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Which yields:

[image]

This is the result of applying gain division to the first image. Note that now the background is almost uniform. This is excellent, because we can apply a **simple auto threshold** to create a *binary mask* containing just the foreground objects, like this:

```
# Convert RGB to grayscale:
grayscaleImage = cv2.cvtColor(gainDivision, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

# Get binary image via Otsu:
_, binaryImage = cv2.threshold(grayscaleImage, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV + cv2.THRESH_OTSU)
```

This is the binary image:

[image]

Now, we have a problem here. The compression artifacts make this mask noisy. We could apply a little bit of [morphology](https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/d9/d61/tutorial_py_morphological_ops.html) to improve the binary blobs, but your image is really small, so I have skipped this step. If you have access to larger, lossless images, you might want to include a cleaning step.

For now I'll simply try to compute the **Minimum Enclosing Circle** of each blob larger than a threshold, and I should get a detection a little bit more robust than Hough's. Let's see:

```
# Find the circle blobs on the binary mask:
contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(binaryImage, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
contoursPoly = [None] * len(contours)

# Store the circles here:
detectedCircles = []

# Alright, just look for the outer bounding boxes:
for i, c in enumerate(contours):

    # Get blob area:
    blobArea = cv2.contourArea(c)
    print(blobArea)

    # Set min area:
    minArea = 100

    # Process only big blobs:
    if blobArea > minArea:

        # Approximate the contour to a circle:
        (x, y), radius = cv2.minEnclosingCircle(c)

        # Compute the center and radius:
        center = (int(x), int(y))
        radius = int(radius)

        # Draw the circles:
        cv2.circle(inputImageCopy, center, radius, (0, 0, 255), 1)
        cv2.line(inputImageCopy, center, center, (0, 255, 0), 2)

        # Store the center and radius:
        detectedCircles.append([center, radius])

cv2.imshow("Circles", inputImageCopy)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Let's see the results drawn onto a deep copy of the original image:

[image]

Not bad. All the circle's data (center and radius) is stored in the `detectedCircles` list. We can print the info like this:

```
# Check out the detected circles:
for i in range(len(detectedCircles)):
    center, r = detectedCircles[i]
    print("Circle #: "+str(i)+" x: "+str(center[0])+" y: "+str(center[1])+" r: "+str(r))
```

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation of your thinking and approach, it makes it easier to look up the things you mentioned, it does make a lot of sense
I can't wait to try this out later, I will give some feedback then

Comment: Does equalizing before the division gain make sense to you?
What would you recommend in cases that contains a coin with a low contrast and/or contains a lot of reflection still? The problem in this cases is that the thresholding almost completely removes those coins leaving only a few pixels that don't even form a shape (for example the picture from set0)